# Do I need to provide 3 or 4 numbers for mkinitrd as kernel version?

Tags: kernel

Suppose the kernel is 2.6.32.9:

```
mkinitrd   /boot/initrd_2.6.32.9.img   2.6.32.9
```

Or

```
mkinitrd   /boot/initrd_2.6.32.img   2.6.32
```

Which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put in the full kernel version as given in one of the subdirectories of `/lib/modules` as the second argument. The first argument can be any filename of your choosing.